# is it legal to charge for wordpress multisite?

Tags: licensing

I want to create a wordpress multisite and charge my members a monthly fee to use it. Is this okay under the license agreement?

Comment: The license is for the code, not the use cases you can imagine. :)

Comment: So yes you can charge money.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The [GNU General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) explicitly allows for charging for redistribution (which you're not actually *doing* in this case):

> You may charge a fee for the physical act of transferring a copy...

...and explicitly allows for unlimited usage rights:

> Activities other than copying, distribution and modification are not covered by this License; they are outside its scope. The act of running the Program is not restricted...

Note that there are already several commercial services based on providing WordPress as a service, including Automattic (wordpress.com), WPEngine, and others.